# Changing Photoshop resize keyboard shortcut

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know Photoshop has 2 hotkeys to change brush size. First one is [] brackets and the second one is "Alt + ctrl + second mouse button".

Is there any way to change it to "Alt + ctrl + second" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I change Photoshop keyboard shortcuts?

Use the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog.

> Photoshop lets you view a list of all shortcuts, and edit or create
>   shortcuts. The Keyboard Shortcuts dialog box serves as a shortcut
>   editor, and includes all commands that support shortcuts, some of
>   which aren’t addressed in the default shortcut set.
>
> Note:
>
> In addition to using keyboard shortcuts, you can access many commands
>   using context-sensitive menus that are relevant to the active tool,
>   selection, or panel. To display a context-sensitive menu, right-click
>   in the document window or panel.
>
> Define new keyboard shortcuts
>
> 1. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Choose Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts.
>    - Choose Window > Workspace > Keyboard Shortcuts & Menus and click the Keyboard Shortcuts tab.
> 2. Choose a set of shortcuts from the Set menu at the top of the Keyboard Shortcuts & Menus dialog box.
> 3. Choose a shortcut type from the Shortcuts For menu:
>
>    - Application Menus
>
>      Lets you customize keyboard shortcuts for items in the menu bar.
>    - Panel Menus
>
>      Lets you customize keyboard shortcuts for items in panel menus.
>    - Tools
>
>      Lets you customize keyboard shortcuts for tools in the toolbox.
> 4. In the Shortcut column of the scroll list, select the shortcut you want to modify.
> 5. Type a new shortcut.
>
>    - If the keyboard shortcut is already assigned to another command or tool in the set, an alert appears. Click Accept to assign the
>        shortcut to the new command or tool and erase the previously assigned
>        shortcut. After you reassign a shortcut, you can click Undo Changes to
>        undo the change, or click Accept and Go To Conflict to assign a new
>        shortcut to the other command or tool.
> 6. When you’re finished changing shortcuts, do one of the following:
>
>    - To save all changes to the current set of keyboard shortcuts, click the Save Set button . Changes to a custom set are saved. If
>        you’re saving changes to the Photoshop Defaults set, the Save dialog
>        box opens. Enter a name for the new set and click Save.
>    - To create a new set based on the current set of shortcuts, click the Save Set As button . In the Save dialog box, enter a name
>        for the new set in the Name text box, and click Save. The new keyboard
>        shortcut set will appear in the pop‑up menu under the new name.
>    - To discard the last saved change without closing the dialog box, click Undo.
>    - To return a new shortcut to the default, click Use Default.
>    - To discard all changes and exit the dialog box, click Cancel.
>
> Note:
>
> If you haven’t saved the current set of changes, you can click Cancel
>   to discard all changes and exit the dialog box.

Source [Customize keyboard shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/customizing-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Comment: "Photoshop lets you view a list of all shortcuts, and edit or create shortcuts" sadly not true. The main problem is where are no second brush size "Alt + ctrl + second" shortcut in menu.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop in Windows OS:

Using Alt key + right mouse button drag right/left to increase/decrease the brush size and up/down to increase/decrease the brush hardness.
This shortcut can't be changed because it's not included among the Tool shortcuts listed in the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog box.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/customizing-keyboard-shortcuts.html